# Counting total rows, rows with null value, rows with zero values, and their ratios on PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
unique_id | group | value_1 | value_2 | value_3
abc_xxx     1        200        null     100
def_xxx     1        0           3       40
ghi_xxx     2        300         1        2
```

that I need to extract the following information from:

- Total number of rows per group
- Count number of rows per group that contains null values.
- Count number of rows per group with zero values.

I can do the first one with a simple groupBy and count

```
df.select().groupBy(group).count()
```

I'm not so sure how to approach the next two which is needed for me to compute the null and zero rate from the total rows per group.

Comment: null values and zero values per column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data= [
    ('abc_xxx', 1, 200, None, 100),
    ('def_xxx', 1, 0,    3,   40 ),
    ('ghi_xxx', 2, 300,  1,    2 ),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['unique_id','group','value_1','value_2','value_3'])
# new edit
df = df\
    .withColumn('contains_null', when(isnull(col('value_1')) | isnull(col('value_2')) | isnull(col('value_3')), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))\
    .withColumn('contains_zero', when((col('value_1')==0) | (col('value_2')==0) | (col('value_3')==0), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))

df.groupBy('group')\
    .agg(count('unique_id').alias('total_rows'), sum('contains_null').alias('null_value_rows'), sum('contains_zero').alias('zero_value_rows')).show()

+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+
|group|total_rows|null_value_rows|zero_value_rows|
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+
|    1|         2|              1|              1|
|    2|         1|              0|              0|
+-----+----------+---------------+---------------+

# total_count = (count('value_1') + count('value_2') + count('value_3'))
# null_count = (sum(when(isnull(col('value_1')), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)) + when(isnull(col('value_2')), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)) + when(isnull(col('value_3')), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))))
# zero_count = (sum(when(col('value_1')==0, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)) + when(col('value_2')==0, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)) + when(col('value_3')==0, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))))

# df.groupBy('group')\
    # .agg(total_count.alias('total_numbers'), null_count.alias('null_values'), zero_count.alias('zero_values')).show()

#+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
#|group|total_numbers|null_values|zero_values|
#+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
#|    1|            5|          1|          1|
#|    2|            3|          0|          0|
#+-----+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: total_numbers in this case should be 2 for group 1 and 1 for group 2. where did the 5 and 3 come from?

Comment: I count all three columns: value1/value2/value3.   if u want count apart, just count value1/2/3 one by one.

Comment: I updated my answer. Count rows of each group.